# Format output of script by PC name and monitor details

Tags: powershell

The code below gets computer monitor's model & serial number remotely from a list of computers in a text file. How do I output the information in a text file like:

```
PC-Name
Model :
Serial number :
```

Code:

```
$users = gc .\computernames.txt

gwmi WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi -computername $users |
  Select @{n="Model";e={[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($_.UserFriendlyName -ne 00)}},
         @{n="Serial Number";e={[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($_.SerialNumberID -ne 00)}} |
  Format-List
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!! both of the answers were perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `PSComputerName` property to your `select` statement to include the computer name in the selected properties, and pipe the output of the `Format-List` statement into `Set-Content` to write the list to a file:

```
gwmi WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi -computername $users |
  Select PSComputerName,
         @{n="Model";e={[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($_.UserFriendlyName -ne 00)}},
         @{n="Serial Number";e={[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($_.SerialNumberID -ne 00)}} |
  Format-List | Set-Content 'C:\path\to\output.txt'
```

If you want exactly the format you outlined in your question you need to build that yourself, e.g. with a custom format string like this:

```
gwmi WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi -computername $users |
  Select PSComputerName,
         @{n="Model";e={[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($_.UserFriendlyName -ne 00)}},
         @{n="Serial Number";e={[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($_.SerialNumberID -ne 00)}} |
  % { "{0}`r`nModel : {1}`r`nSerial Number : {2}" -f $_.PSComputerName, $_.Model, $_.'Serial Number' } |
  Set-Content 'C:\path\to\output.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best is to use WMI, to get the Model you can use Win32_ComputerSystem class and to get the SN you can use win32_bios, here's how to get both and for each computer and export it to text file:

To get the monitor or any other WMI Class just replace the class and the properties, to get the available properties use `Gwmi win32_logicaldisk | Get-Member` (or any other class of course) look for the properties and change as needed, good luck

```
$Computers = gc .\computernames.txt
$Array = @()
Foreach ($Computer in $computers)
{
$Result = "" | Select Name,Model,SerialNumber
$WMI_CS = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computer
$WMI_Bios = Get-WmiObject Win32_Bios -ComputerName $computer
$Result.Name = $WMI_CS.Name
$Result.Model = $WMI_CS.Model
$Result.SerialNumber = $WMI_Bios.SerialNumber
$Array += $Result
}

$Array | Format-List | Out-File C:\Report.txt
```